# File cannot be find on website (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure

I have web app that write video files to folder inside project

After this it display video to view

With writing is all ok.

But when I try to display video I get this error

> The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

When I run website on local machine all okay and video is displaying

I face this problem only on hosting (Azure)

Here is code of controller

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PostRecordedAudioVideo()
    {
        foreach (string upload in Request.Files)
        {
            var path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "uploads/";
            var file = Request.Files[upload];

            file?.SaveAs(Path.Combine(path, Request.Form[0]));
        }
        return Json(Request.Form[0]);
    }
```

Interesting thing in this. I see this file in folder when connect to server via ftp

Here is screenshot
[image]

But in console I have this
[image]
Where my problem may be?

Comment: Watch the network tab in the Chrome Developer Tools. Does it try to retrieve the file from the correct URL? What happens if you access the URL directly in the browser? Does it show the video or attempt to download it?

Comment: Could be a permissions issue. Make sure that the App Pool identity has access to read that file and directory.

Comment: How I can give acess? @ChrisPratt

Comment: Can you help me? @ChrisPratt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not entirely the answer you're looking for, but you might want to look into storing your video files in Azure blob storage:

- This current approach is not going to work once your app scales beyond a
  single node.
- You will lose uploads if your webapp is redeployed
- You will run into scale limits quickly, making this potentially
  very expensive.

If you use blob storage, you offload the video traffic from the webapp by either linking to the file directly in a public container, or by generating a SAS token on-the-fly for controlled access.

Comment: Where I can find tutorial how to do this?

Comment: You mean azure storage account?

Comment: Yes, as azure storage account. Have a look at this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/aspnet/overview/developing-apps-with-windows-azure/building-real-world-cloud-apps-with-windows-azure/unstructured-blob-storage. It deals with an image, but I think the concept roughly applies to your videos.

Answer (score 0):

Just need to write this in config

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
        <remove fileExtension=".webm" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".webm" mimeType="video/webm" />
    </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```